# Shared element transition between two different applications in Android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

Is there a possibility to use shared element transition between two different apps?

Comment: Theoretically, shared-element transitions should work even if the two Activities belong to separate applications. Obviously the two applications will need to coordinate with each other in order to get the transition working properly (i.e. both will need to set the same `transitionName` on the shared element, etc.). Have you tested this out yourself?

Comment: @AlexLockwood I didn't but I will since nobody else did ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, shared elements will work between different applications. You have to agree on a common name to share between the two applications. Normally this is done with the transitionName as @AlexLockwood suggests, but the views don't have to carry the same name. It just happens that if you do, you get a lot of help for free.

There is an important aspect of sharing elements between applications -- they **must** be in the same task. The Activity Options will be rejected if they aren't in the same task.

If you want to use different transitionNames in the layout, you just do this:

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
    this, view, "remoteName");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Now, if the remote application used "remoteName" for the transitionName in its layout file, it doesn't have to do anything special. However, if it uses a different name, it must map the name to a view:

```
setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names,
                Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
            // You may want to validate that names contains "remoteName"
            // if this can be instantiated with different shared elements
            sharedElements.put("remoteName", findViewById(R.id.mySharedElement));
        }
    });
```

This functionality is important when you share to something that has a list of views, any of which may be shared. For example, a list of contacts will have all contact images with different transitionNames. Going from a single contact to that list of contacts, you need to map the single shared contact to one of the contacts in the list.

Comment: So it's theoretically possible to define two different transition resources in different apps?

Comment: Yes. It will behave in the same way as if you use different transitions on different Activities in the same application. The shared element exit transition works on the calling activity and will delay the transfer of the shared element to the called activity until it completes. The shared element enter transition moves the shared element(s) from the initial location to the final position. The exit transition works on the calling activity and works against the leaving views. The enter activity works on the called activity and affects entering views.

Comment: @GeorgeMount You mention that the shared element Activity Options will be rejected if the calling and called activities aren't in the same task. Is this also true for exit/enter content transitions that don't have any shared elements?

Comment: Yes. I suppose it wouldn't be necessary to reject Activity transitions without shared elements, but they are currently. We could consider changing that in the future.